# Password protect a file in adobe acrobat pro on a button click?

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I want to password protect file in adobe acrobat using a button click. I think it can be done using javascript, can anybody help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

Though it is possible to do via JavaScript, you do not ***need*** JavaScript. You can add a button to the toolbar that password protects your PDF by first creating an Action using the Action Wizard. Then creating a Custom Tool that executes the new Action, then adding that new Custom tool to the toolbar.